# cbd generate - exec: not started

Tags: docker, ansible, cloudbreak

I followed [this documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Cloudbreak/Cloudbreak-2.7.0/content/azure-launch/index.html) to install Hortonworks cloudbreak.

Everything goes through fine as long as I create an instance on Azure and execute the commands specified.

Now I want to automate the installation of cloudbreak through Ansible. It's all simple commands, I could easily write the tasks in ansible but at the step 
cbd generate
I see an error: "exec: not started"

This happens only when I am trying through ansible, If I try executing the commands manually, I can get the cloudbreak working.

I also tried using the shell module in ansible and copy paste the commands from the link and created the task. But it still gives the same problem. I am not able to proceed further from here.

- Ansible version: 2.4.2.0
- Cloudbreak Version: 2.7.0 (Latest is 2.7.1, We want to use 2.7.0)
- OS: Tried both on Centos 7.3 and 7.4
- Docker version: 1.13.1

Looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: edit the question, I don't understand what is "cbd" so replace this acronym with the real word, also provide the part of the code that doesn't work, else I don't see anyway to provide you any help

Comment: "cbd" is the Hortonworks cloudbreak deployer. cbd is the command to tweak the cloudbreak deployer.
Here I am trying to install cloudbreak on centos 7.3, as suggested in the documentation. You can find the documentation in the hyperlink.

Comment: sorry but it is to you to provide relevant information, you did not even provide the code that don't work.

Comment: I am not coding. Just using the opensource build to install. People with Hadoop and Hortonworks installation background would get this question :)

Comment: What error do you get? And during which task? And what is the command you are trying to execute via shell? If you can manually run it fine, but not through ansible "shell" module, Then would suggest you to cross check your environment variable when you run using ansible.

Comment: I did try by passing path through ansible environment. It didn't help. Finally after spending few days, I figured out it was the problem with the disc mount. Explained in detail in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with Disc mount script I was using in Automation. These are the steps I was following for Automation:

1. Create centos 7.3 instance on azure through Terraform
2. Run Ansible playbook to perform disc mount and install Hortonworks cloudbreak

There was an issue with /etc/fstab entry for the data disc, which is updated by the disc mount script. So when I try to execute 'cbd' command outside the data disc it went through fine. If I execute the command inside the data disc (In my case I had mounted the data disc on the path /media, So whenever I change the directory to media and execute cbd I could see the error cbd: exec not found)

**I corrected the fstab entry like below:

UUID={uuid_name} /media ext4 defaults 0 0**

Script was updating like below:

UUID={uuid_name} /media ext4 noatime,nodiratime,nodev,noexec,nosuid 1 2

Really not sure what made cbd not to work with fstab entries. After changing it to defaults I am able to get the Cloudbreak deployer working through Ansible.